# Replace items with RewriteRule using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use the Url rewrite using "RewriteRule".

I would use this link to show a new article in my blog:

```
https://www.example.com/article/how-to-visit-italy-in-winter
```

The original script (including vars) is

```
https://www.example.com/post.php?idpost=how-to-visit-italy-in-winter
```

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article/$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .$ https://www.example.com/post.php?idpost=$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't work, the browser redirect to:

> https://www.example.com/post.php?idpost=

I'm trying to resolve about 2 days witout success :(
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You rule looks fine except for two things . Your `$1` back reference is undefined and empty as you are not capturing  any URI. To capture parts of the uri you need to use Regex capture-groups `(.*)` . 
2) You need to use an absolute path instead of the full url as your RewriteRule`s destination if you want to silently redirect the url.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article/$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule article/(.+) /post.php?idpost=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect :) I need to study regex conditions.. I see that the destination page will display like as "https://www.example.com/post.php?idpost=how-to-visit-italy-in-winter", it's possible to change also the url of the browser? (navigation bar). i can add other code into the .taccess? Thanls so much :)